# Algorithm for TripleSum Calculation O(n) time, Java

Tags: java, algorithm

The task at hand is to come up with an algorithm that takes in an array of non-negative integers, and returns a boolean value depending on whether the array contains 3 numbers which add up to 225.

The hard part is to write this is O(n) time.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It sounds like this is homework. You should attempt to solve the problem as efficiently as you can first. Then look at your solution and try to improve upon it. Once you have some code you can ask for more help on how to improve upon it.

Comment: @shekharsuman it actually matches 3 sum better, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM, as it isn't "any set" but rather "a set of 3". It is O(n^2) rather than NPComplete. Interestingly, it would seem that if you could solve it in O(n) time, you'd still win the Nobel prize in mathematics...

Comment: To answer OP's question "If we could solve that problem we'd all be millionaires and not sitting here answering questions on stack overflow."

Comment: @MadScienceDreams---it's field medal in the area of mathematics,not the Nobel prize.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams This is not 3sum since the values are non-negative.

Comment: @AtLeastItsNotBio cool question cuz I was asked such a question in my interview. I solve it with 2 for loops and it was right, but the interviewer asked me how you gonna do this with hashmap and I said what???????!!!! :O by case was two numbers not three

Comment: @KickButtowski Put the numbers in a hash set, then go through each number x again and if the desired sum is S, look for S-x in the set. If it's there you are done. That's O(n).

Comment: I don't quite understand what the algorithm has to do, what do you mean by "the hard part is to write this is O(n) time" ?
The algorithm has to return true if 3 numbers in the array give 225 summed up? And return false if there is none?

Answer (score 4):

Just thinking out loud ATM as I'm not at a computer right now but how about:

Scan through the numbers once recording a count of each - discard any greater than 225.

Perform one pass on the counts to determine the answer.

Must be O(n) as we pass the original carry once - the rest is O(225) which vanishes.

**Added** - now I have a computer.

I have missed some edge cases but this looks like a fair implementation of the algorithm:

```
boolean canAdd3ToMakeX(int[] v, int x) {
    // How many of each number.
    int[] counts = new int[x];
    // O(n) part.
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        if (v[i] >= 0 && v[i] < x) {
            counts[v[i]] += 1;
        }
    }
    // O(k) part. :) - NOT the most efficient - but the most obvious.
    for (int a = 0; a < x; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < x; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < x; c++) {
                if (a + b + c == x && counts[a] > 0 && counts[b] > 0 && counts[c] > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void test(int[] t) {
    System.out.println("Can - " + Arrays.toString(t) + " = " + canAdd3ToMakeX(t, 225));
}

public void test() {
    test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5});
    test(new int[]{1, 2, 222});
    test(new int[]{100, 100, 25});

}
```

It certainly delivers the correct answer to my test cases but I believe there are problems with my solution that would make it unacceptable for submission as homework. I leave the solution to those problems to the student (hint: try `test(new int[]{100, 25})`.

Comment: Yeah the point here clearly is that you can sort in O(n) since we only have a constant-sized set of values to consider. This should be the rough way to do it.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I have a question.  how is it possible to solve this with hashmap?

Comment: The solution using hashmaps is described on the wikipedia page for [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).

Comment: I think you still have a nested loop so the time would be O(255*255) right? Still O(1).

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - Still O(n) from the first loop over the n elements - after that it is O(k*225) which collapses to O(1).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Should probably be 225^k but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yeah I meant the nested loop is over 255 values so the nested loop itself is O(255^2)=O(1) and the full algo is O(n). What is k in this? The number of numbers adding up to 255?

Answer (score 1):

Since maybe it's not entirely clear how to go about it from @OldCurmudgeon's answer, here's a bit of explanation on the details:

- Since we only have non-negative numbers, the only numbers we have to consider are those from `0` to `225`, which means we can Bucketsort in O(n) because there's a constant number of buckets to deal with (just make an array of 226 lists and add occurrence of value `i` to the ith list or whatever your favorite way of bucketsorting is).
- Once that's done, take the sorted array of values between `0` and `225`. Fix a pointer `pointer = array.length - 1` for the largest element of the sum at `array[pointer]`. Now check in O(n) whether you can produce `225 - array[pointer]` (the next bullet point explains how to do this) - if you can, then there are three values in your array that sum to `225`, if you can't, recurse by decreasing `pointer` until it points to the next lower value.
- To check an array in O(n) whether it contains two values `a` and `b` such that `a + b = c`, you first put the contents of the array into a hashmap to count their multiplicities, then you loop through the array and for every entry `a[i]`, you check whether `c - a[i]` is in the hashmap, and if `a[i] = c - a[i]`, then you check whether the value occurs at least twice. If you find such an entry at some point, you can sum two values to get `c`, if you never do, you can't.

Notice that if we fix a constant value which we want to sum to, we can actually allow for an arbitrary number of non-negative addends and still end up with O(n) by applying this approach inductively. All of this is of course expected time due to the hashing, and also: for large values (which I don't think anyone would consider `225` to be here), calling this approach O(n) is technically correct, but a bit of eyewash.

---

Another way to do what OldCurmudgeon suggested would be to sort, then try all (worst case, depending on how often values appear) 225^3 possibilities and see whether any of them work. This will also be O(n) since it's dominated by the sorting and O(225^3) = O(1) and will also generalize to sums with an arbitrary fixed number of addends, but depending on the number of addends and the value we want to sum to, it may be even worse than the above with hashing.